# Can I deactivate the text marker function in iBooks?

Tags: books

Is it possible to deactivate the text marker function in iBooks? I often use the dictionary lookup, but accidentally, I activate the marker function quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option to disable the text marker function.